# Почему изменилась переменная const

Tags: c

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 int main(void) {
  3     unsigned short str[5+1];
  4     const unsigned short length = sizeof(str)/sizeof(str[0]);
  5     unsigned short x;
  6
  7     printf("Значение length = %hu\n", length); /* выведет 6 */
  8
  9     for(x=0; x<length-1; x++)
 10         str[x] = x;
 11
 12     str[x+1] = 5;
 13
 14     printf("Значение length = %hu\n", length); /* выведет 5 */
 15
 16     return 0;
 17 }
```

Прога чисто экспериментальная. Вопрос: почему изменился length? Если убрать 12: то все норм. Как код в 12: влияет на length? Или дело в другом? Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: а где ты пишешь?
в dev-c++ оба раза 6

Comment: Вы производите доступ в массив за его границей. Согласно правилам языка, так делать **нельзя**, это запускает undefined behaviour. После этого имеет право **все правила отменяются** и имеет право произойти всё, что угодно: константы станут переменными, функция `read_file` превратится в `format_disk`, а разыменование указателя настучит на вас в полицию.

Просто не делайте так никогда.

Comment: Выравнивание, регистровые переменные, оптимизация  - много факторов дадут разброс поведения даже в одном и том же компиляторе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что так случилось, что переменная `length` находится в стеке сразу после `str[5+1]`. И строка, которая произвела запись за пределы массива, долбануда именно в эту память, записав туда другое значение.

Comment: @klopp Точно. Надо str[x+1] = 5; заменить на str[x] = 5; Спасибо.

Comment: @dr_kraken, (удалил предыдущий комментарий, потому что неверно прочитал код)

    for(x=0; x<length-1; x++)
        str[x] = x;

Цикл оборвется в тот момент, когда условие перестанет выполняться. фактически это случится тогда, когда `x` достигнет (`length - 1`) - он проинкрементируется **до** сравнения, и уже после сравнения будет приянто решение, выполнять блок кода или прерывать цикл. `x + 1` же будет равен в `length`, или в 6.

Comment: В строке 12, однако, `x+1` в этой точке равно 6. BTW, ошибка "плавающая", всё зависит исключительно от доброй воли компилятора, как именно он распределит по памяти локальные переменные (может вообще length и х засунуть в регистры, а может и выровнять переменные на много байт => и запись проскочит в никуда, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Это только предположения, но:

1. Задается str
2. Сразу за str в памяти задается length
3. Сразу за str, в length + 1, пишется пять. Это значение занято length, и эта память перезаписывается. Формально переменную никто не трогает, поэтому по этому поводу компилятор не ругается.

Comment: @Etki В length+1 ничего не пишется. О чем вы?

Comment: @dr_kraken смотрите комментарий под ответом @klopp. Под length + 1 я конечно имел в виду "последний элемент str + 1".